# How to index and get a value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics

I have a function in c# as following

```
GetbyId<TKey>(TKey key)
{
   // do something

  }
```

The function is called this way
      GetbyId(string[] key);

Since you can see that TKey is string array so I want to find length and access each element how can I do that I cannot change the function signature only can override it

Comment: Question is not clear at all. What do you exactly want?

Comment: I think my answer will help you to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] arr = (object)key as string[];
if(arr != null)
{
    int length = arr.Length;
    //more code
}
```

Comment: IllidanS4 you are correct i did something like this object k = key;    int len = ((string[])key).Length;  Dion your solution will give compilation error

Comment: @user3048027 yes, I will delete is as soon as I can. You should mark this as the answer to your question if it fits your needs.

Answer (score -1):

I found out answer by myself don't know if this is right approach and the solution is
     var something= key;
Now I can loop in something

Comment: This doesn't look like a proper solution. `something` would still be of type `TKey`.